# UDP Networking with multiple sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, asio

I'm trying to create a server application which essentially controls multiple sockets for data sent over a local network.

I firstly did some tests both on linux and windows with they're libraries (such as Winsock) and also with the ASIO library as well, but the goal is to have it run in a linux enviroment.

The complete application would be something that opens ***N*** sockets (possibily multithreading asynchronously) and essentially does nothing untill every socket has received some data. Only at that point, the server will analyze the packets and do some conversions stuff. This is because those data will have different structures, and based on this a different connection has been requested (that's at least what I'm asked to do).
So at a fixed time, I would have ***N*** packets available, which will then be "re-composed" by the server.

Essentially, each socket is somewhat "bound" to the data-type it's supposed to receive.

Now the problem is that I'm not understanding which solution to implement for this scenario, because I'm "forced" to use the UDP protocol, as well as using different sockets.
As far as I know, for this kind of stuff TCP protocol is the one used, so that each socket-pair can establish a connection and do its own stuff.

Moreover, I cannot use a single UDP socket to receive everything. This essentially because:
A- I've been asked differently; B- even if timing of packets will not be a real problem, I could not receive them all mixed up, 'cause it would need sending additional information from the clients (on which I do not have control).

In fact now I understand why there's not that much of documentation available about UDP scenarios. I would gladly switch to TCP, so that at least I've would have a rough idea of what to do, but at the moment I can't.

Can you help me out to understand better the situation?

Comment: If I was implementing this, I would create N UDP sockets, set them all to non-blocking mode, and then have an event loop that loops around blocking inside `select()` until one (or more) of the sockets is ready-for-read.  That has the advantage of handling everything in a single thread, where co-ordination of behavior based on the state of multiple sockets' data-streams is easier to implement safely.

Comment: Ok, I've understood the principle, but I'm missing the role of `select()`.
I'm thinking about your solution like for instance having a main loop which: checks recvfrom(S1), then checks rcvfrom(S2) and so on, with those functions returning immediately 0 if no data is available. Right? But what about the select?

Comment: the role of `select()` is to *not return until there is something to do*.  If you just naively call `recvfrom()` on each socket in a loop, that will sort-of work, but you'll be using 100% of the CPU cycles of one core on your machine, with 99.99% of them being wasted checking and re-checking sockets that still don't have any data available to give you.  With `select()`, you only use CPU cycles in the event that a UDP packet has actually been received, and then your program can go right back to blocking/sleeping inside `select()` as soon as you've handled the packet.  It's much more efficient.

Comment: Right. I just had not quite understood _how_ select worked. Now it's clear, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, you can monitor multiple ports with the `select` function.  It takes lists of ports to check for readability, writability, or errors and returns lists of ports in the requested state.

Below is an example watching 5 ports for readability, and exits when all 5 ports have received something:

```py
import socket
import select

N = 5
base_port = 5000

# Create N sockets and bind to ports 5000 to 5000+N-1:
socks = [socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) for _ in range(N)]
for i,s in enumerate(socks):
    s.bind(('',base_port+i))

# Flags to track that something was received on a particular port
got = [False] * N

while not all(got):
    # Watch all N sockets for readability only
    readable,writable,errors = select.select(socks,[],[])

    # Only a socket that has something to read will be in "readable"
    for s in readable:
        port = s.getsockname()[1] # which port was it
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
        print(f'From {port}: {data}')
        got[port-5000] = True

print("Got'em all!")
```

Demo (client)

```py
>>> from socket import *
>>> s=socket(type=SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.sendto(b'abc',('localhost',5001))
3
>>> s.sendto(b'abc',('localhost',5002))
3
>>> s.sendto(b'abc',('localhost',5003))
3
>>> s.sendto(b'abc',('localhost',5004))
3
>>> s.sendto(b'abc',('localhost',5000))
3
```

Demo (server)

```
From 5001: b'abc'
From 5002: b'abc'
From 5003: b'abc'
From 5004: b'abc'
From 5000: b'abc'
Got'em all!
```

Comment: That's precisely what I had in mind, test-client included. I got a bit confused at first when talking about the select. Reading the code helped a lot.
Thank you!